# Yii2 + AngularJS PrettyURL enable to work

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, .htaccess

I'm using Yii2 with AngularJS. I have to call different pages like about us, contact us etc. But my Pretty URL not working Properly. I need PrettyUrl like this:

`localhost/angularjsyii/frontend/web/site/#/login`

Current Url which is not working: `localhost/angularjsyii/frontend/web/site#!/#%2Flogin`

#### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

#### main.php(`<navbar>`)

```
   <?php
use frontend\assets\AppAsset;

/* @var $this \yii\web\View */

AppAsset::register($this);
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>" ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>My Angular Yii Application</title>
<?php $this->head() ?>

<script>paceOptions = {ajax: {trackMethods: ['GET', 'POST']}};</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/pace.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/themes/red/pace-theme-minimal.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a base href="/angularjsyii/frontend/web/"></a>
</head>
<body>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
<div class="wrap">
    <nav class="navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar" role="navigation" bs-navbar>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button ng-init="navCollapsed = true" ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed" type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/angularjsyii/frontend/web/site/index">My Company</a>
            </div>
            <div ng-class="!navCollapsed && 'in'" ng-click="navCollapsed=true" class="collapse navbar-collapse" >
                <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right nav">
                    <li data-match-route="/">
                        <a href="/">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-match-route="/about">
                        <a href="/about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-match-route="/contact">
                        <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-match-route="/login">
                        <a href="/login">Login</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div ng-view>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">

        <p class="pull-right"><?= Yii::powered() ?> <?= Yii::getVersion() ?></p>
    </div>
</footer>

<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

#### app.js (For routing)

```
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('app', [
        'ngRoute',      //$routeProvider
        'mgcrea.ngStrap'//bs-navbar, data-match-route directives
    ]);

    app.config(['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/index.html'
                }).
                when('/about', {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/about.html'
                }).
                when('/contact', {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/contact.html'
                }).
                when('/login', {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/login.html'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    templateUrl: 'partials/404.html'
                });
        }
    ])

;
```

#### config/main.php

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    // Disable index.php
    'showScriptName' => false,
    // Disable r= routes
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable HTML5 mode in AngularJS to disable hashPrefix `!` in your route.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/index.html'
        }).
        when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/about.html'
        }).
        when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/contact.html'
        }).
        when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/login.html'
        }).
        otherwise({
            templateUrl: 'partials/404.html'
        });
    }
]);
```

From reading the [$location documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) of AngularJS:

> #### Relative links
>
> Be sure to check all relative links, images, scripts etc. You must
>   either specify the url base in the head of your main html file (`<base href="/my-base">`) or you must use absolute urls (starting with `/`)
>   everywhere because relative urls will be resolved to absolute urls
>   using the initial absolute url of the document, which is often
>   different from the root of the application.

In your case the base href should be something like this `<a base href="/angularjsyii/frontend/web/site">`. Now you dont need `#` on your URL anymore. Change your routes like:

```
<li data-match-route="/login">
    <a href="/login">Login</a>
</li>
```

The URL should finaly look like: `localhost/angularjsyii/frontend/web/site/login` which is more pretty.

Comment: In which file i have to put this **$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);**?

Comment: Modified my answer.

Comment: `<li data-match-route="/login">
    <a href="/login">Login</a>
</li>` Directely take me to the **localhost/login** and thows It Works!

Comment: @Akkie Have you configured the base-href?

Comment: You mean this Url: **public $baseUrl = '@web';**?

Comment: For example yes. But I dont know your application structure. It could work with @web or with `<a base href="/angularjsyii/frontend/web/site">` or `<a base href="/angularjsyii/frontend/web/">`. Mixing AngularJS routing with Yii2 isnt a good approach at all.

Comment: okk It's my mistake i m using yii2 baseurl. so help me to set baseurl of angular.

Comment: Put `<a base href="/angularjsyii/frontend/web">` or `<a base href="/angularjsyii/frontend/web/site">` into your header HTML part of your template. It should be located in `views/layouts/main.php` by default.

Comment: **Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=TypeError%3A…jsyii%2Ffrontend%2Fweb%2Fassets%2F210b05e5%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A20%3A1)**  angular.js:line 6  I think it do not get my files on path right?

Comment: Please read my answer carefuly: `Be sure to check all relative links, images, scripts etc. You must either specify the url base in the head of your main html file `. Have you done this? I promise your ressources are not loaded correctly anymore.

Comment: Modified my Question follow this file:=> main.php(<navbar>)

Comment: Your PHP template doesnt matter here. Please check your web debugger @network tab to get information about the wrong ressource paths. You need to configure your Yii2 assets path in the right way while using `<a base href>` - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html

Comment: @Akkie glad to help :)

Comment: I need to work my project like this: [Follow this link](http://blog.neattutorials.com/examples/angular-yii2-auth/frontend/web/#/)